# How to update dataTable in ajax response in grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, gsp

I have a template with table that uses Jquery data table. In whole page refresh i got the data table design correctly. But when i update table with ajax , i could n't get data table with design. It render normal table without design. What is the mistake i have done.

**list.gsp:**

```
<div id="lists">
    <g:render template="template1"></g:render>
</div>

<g:formRemote name="saveParameter" url="[action:'save']" update="lists">

</g:formRemote>
```

**_template1.gsp**

```
<table class="gs"> //This is a data table

</table>
```

I have included file for datatable in main.gsp that is under the layout folder in views

**In main.gsp:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css')}" />

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css')}"
    type="text/css" />

<g:javascript library='jquery' />
<r:layoutResources />
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" />
<g:javascript library="datatables" src="jquery.dataTables.js" />
<g:javascript src="dataTable.js" />
```

**In dataTable.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.gs').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
            "bSortable" : false,
            "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
        },{ sWidth: '20px', aTargets: [ '_all' ] }]
});

$('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').css('padding-right','15px');

});
```

**In controller save action,**

```
def save(Integer max) {
      .......
      render (template:"template1", model: [.........])
}
```

Comment: You are rendering list template from your action but list is a view that you have posted. Or _list is an another gsp?

Comment: ya.here i have changed template1 to reduce confusion. In my code i have _list as template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `jquery.dataTables.js`, so I am not familiar with this. But as your code says: you are sending _template1.gsp as ajax response. Because document.ready was already being executed and hence in the ajax response `dataTable` properties are not applied.

To solve this problem add following code in your _template1.gsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.gs').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
                "bSortable" : false,
                "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
            },{ sWidth: '20px', aTargets: [ '_all' ] }]
        });

        $('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').css('padding-right','15px');
});
</script> 
<table class="gs"> //This is a data table
    ....
</table>
```

or

```
<g:javascript src="dataTable.js" />
```

Comment: For second option I am not sure, if it works please inform me. Thanks..,.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is the problem.                        function createDataTable() {
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 createDataTable();

});
I changed the datatable.js. I have called the function in onComplete.<g:formRemote name="saveParameter" url="[action:'save']"
   update="lists" onComplete="createDataTable()">